# Is display:inline-block meant to break selection of the whole block it's contained within?

Tags: html, css, display

I've been playing with clicking around on various things on man.openbsd.org that's powered by the new [`mandoc`](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/usr.bin/mandoc/), with `/mandoc.css` having `display: inline-block;` for things like `.An` and `.Nm`…

Specifically, as a minimal case, if you go onto http://man.openbsd.org/intro.1, clicking within an element that's `display: inline-block` only extends the selection within said element (e.g., only within "intro" in the text below), however, selecting an element *before* or *after* said `inline-block` element makes the line appear broken, as the selection breaks at the above point of the single `inline-block` element appearing within the middle of the line.

```css
.An, .Ar, .Cd, .Cm, .Dv, .Em, .Er, .Ev, .Fa, .Fd, .Fl, .Fn, .Ft,
.Ic, code.In, .Lb, .Lk, .Ms, .Mt, .Nd, code.Nm, .Pa, .Rs,
.St, .Sx, .Sy, .Va, .Vt, .Xr {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; }
```

```html
An <code class="Nm">intro</code> manual for section 1 first appeared in
  <span class="Ux">Version&nbsp;6 AT&amp;T UNIX</span>.
```

E.g., above, multi-clicking within **"intro"** extends the selection only for the whole "intro", as should probably be expected; yet multi-clicking on **"An "** before the **"intro"**, makes the selection always stop before **"intro"**, instead of extending for the whole line as might be expected (and what would happen if there was no `inline-block` in the first place).

Is this intentional with the specs, or is it a bug within my Firefox ESR?  And, if so, is there a workaround?  E.g., the above example is pretty minimalistic, but I think it'd be useful to have `inline-block` for other elements like the full name and email address to appear together as an inline-block, yet still have the whole paragraph that they appear within to work as a single block as well.

Comment: I multiclick on "An" and get whole sentece selected - chrome/MacOs

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski you are clicking the example in the code snippet, try going to the original website that he linked above and doing it again

Comment: It works on original website too (on chrome and safari) - but in ff there is a problem which you describe